# Touchpad can't be detected( Surface Pro 3)

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, synaptics, surface

```
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                    id=2  [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer              id=4  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Abyssus                     id=8  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Surface Type Cover            id=9  [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05                   id=12 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ NTRG0001:01 1B96:1B05 Pen               id=13 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard             id=5  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                               id=6  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Surface Pro 3/4 Buttons                 id=7  [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft LifeCam Front                 id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft LifeCam Rear                  id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

As you can see my razer mouse can be detected.I don't know the touchpad is included in the type cover or not.Now the touchpad can be used as a usual mouse, but the multifinger action can't work.

I tried

```
$ synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

it comes

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

I'm new to Linux,don't know anything about Synaptics.
Ubuntu version : 16.04
Kernal : 4.8.0-41-generic

Tell me how did this happen and how can i fix it. Thank you guys!Thank a lot!